# Connecting a MIDI synthesizer

Tags: sound, keyboard, midi

I recently got an old second-hand [Yamaha PSR-350 synthesizer keyboard](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalkeyboards/portable_keyboards/psr-350/?mode=model). I don't have any trouble playing, but I would like to make use of the MIDI function. There are 2 MIDI ports, midi-in and midi-out.

I bought a midi-usb interface and tried to connect it to my laptop but I can't seem to find how it works. What I would like to do is for example to write sheet music in MuseScore with my keyboard.

Here is a screenshot of QJackCtl: [image](http://postimg.org/image/c0sxljhwj/)

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it, the trick was swapping the IN and OUT plugs. Also, LMMS did a great job. Rub grune answer is worth looking into though, and especially this link I found in the post he refers to: http://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/usb-midi-controllers-and-making-music-with-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

You will need to load some software. Use synaptic.

1. Be sure `aconnect` is installed.  This enables the midi to pc connection.
2. Edit [`jack` and `qjackctl`. these are basic.].  If you install `rosegarden` from synaptic, jack will auto-install.  Be sure to enable the real time processing during install.
3. `patchage`. This is an extremely useful tool to establish/verify the connections.
4. `rosegarden`.  This provides the sequencer and music notater all in one pkg.
5. `qsynth`.  This provides the means to hear your midi files and play with the output.
6. `linux-lowlatency`. Critical. You must install this kernel, else rosegarden will not work.

After all the above are installed, you need to check `rosegarden` setup to ensure it loads the `soundfont` and passes to your sound card. If no soundfont, you get no sound from your sound card.  The sound font should be in `/usr/share/sounds/sf2`  (I use `fluidR3_gm.sf2`) and it should come with qsynth.

For more information, read this link:
[Step-by-step to run a midi keyboard input device? 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147052/step-by-step-to-run-a-midi-keyboard-input-device-12-04)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try setting the input Midi device to "24:USB2.0-MIDI" and the output device to "129:MuseScore". I'm not a frequent Ubuntu user so I've never had to face that kind of problem but this should normally work!