# Volume keys does not work Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keys

I have a bug with Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th Gen (with Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS installed) when it comes to using the Volume up/down keys. It just does not work, the rest is OK (e.g. the brightness keys work OK). I tried  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978789/volume-control-not-working) but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: I had some volume and brightness key problems on my PC (another brand) in Ubuntu 18.10 and 19.04. They were not working sometimes (but, not always). After upgrading to 19.10 they seem to be working perfectly all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't try that, but I can add to the problem that sometimes they work, while some others they don't.

Comment: Until you upgrade to something newer, you can adjust volume and brightness from the top right menu using the mouse.