# System volume doesn't change app volume

Tags: sound, volume-control, pipewire

I recently set up a dual boot laptop (Lenovo Yoga pro 7) with Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm having troubles with the volume control. At the moment the system volume slider doesn't change the volume of apps like Spotify, Firefox, etc. I can change those volumes manually in the sound app but the system volume slider is completely useless. At zero is silent and at the lowest volume is whatever the volume of the app playing music is. This happens only when playing sounds through the laptop speakers, when using bluethoot headphones there is no problem.

This is the output of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3852
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 185, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 601d190000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 601d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3850
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 601d19c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
```

and of `pactl info | grep '^Server Name'`

```
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.48)
```

I tried adding `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to `alsa-base.conf` (as suggested in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978789/volume-control-not-working)) and also the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1204558/524705). Any help is appreciated also let me know if more info is needed.

**Update 27/09/23**: Adding element master before element PCM doesn't work (as suggested [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=91453) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119938/audio-volume-doesnt-change/1204558#1204558)).

Adding

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

just before

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

Comment: I filled a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2049995) with similar issue. I've already tried to boot with a Manjaro USB live with Gnome and there the volume works as expected.

Comment: try ``alsamixer''

Comment: @Jose Pimentel filled a bug report with similar issue. He has already tried to boot with a Manjaro USB live with Gnome and there the volume works as expected. (Copied from comment "answer")