# Bass speakers not working on Lenovo Yoga Pro 9 14IRP8, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, alsa, lenovo

Folks, I have recently purchased this laptop:
https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/Yoga/Yoga_Pro_9_14IRP8

And I can only get the front speakers working on Ubuntu 22.04 which results in the sound being not great to say the least.

From reading around I found out that the laptop comes with two sets of speakers like many new Yoga laptops and both of them are supposed to be playing at the same time:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1926165

Same issue on Fedora:
https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/problem-with-sound-on-new-lenovo-laptops/72456

I was not able to get the speakers running with the tricks above, does anyone have an idea? Thank you in advance.

I am currently running the kernel: 6.2.0-33-generic.

Comment: Did you run `alsamixer` to check whether all speakers are enabled?

Comment: Yes, I can see the bass speakers enabled, but the other set is at 0 and I am not allowed to increase the levels.

Comment: How about `sudo alsamixer`?

Comment: It did not help, I tried enabling in pulseaudio as well, but the speaker level in alsamixer is fixed at 0 and I cannot change it.

Comment: I also tried this: https://github.com/thiagotei/linux-realtek-alc287/tree/main/lenovo-legion

Comment: Which resulted in no sound being played back, not even the weak one. So I reverted the change.

Comment: I also found this: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555

But I really do not want to build my own kernel.

Comment: It would be useful to know why you can't change the volume level from `alsamixer`. You might try an `amixer` command, just to see what kind of error message you get. The command should be something like `amixer -c <card-number> set <control> <value>` as explained [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/alsa-utilities-manage-linux-audio-command-line/).

Comment: It says `Invalid command!` I listed the devices with amixer and the "Speaker" does not have volume control listed as an available command, only `Capabilities: pswitch`.

Comment: That makes sense, as the bass speakers are probably intended to play at the same volume as the treble speakers. However, it appears that you can override this with an `alsa` plugin. If you're comfortable with doing some experiments, you could copy and paste the `softvol` plugin found [here] (https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html#pcm_plugins_softvol) into your `~/asoundrc` file. Modify as needed. This *should* enable you to control their volume from `alsamixer`. Note: I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: I meant `~/.asoundrc`.

Comment: So I read through it and right now I am not feeling that experimental since reverting the changes if they don't work is not about just deleting some files. I use the laptop for work and "terrible sound is better than no sound" is what I am thinking. I agree that there is a good chance to get it working like that, but from what I have seen in other places, it is a drivers issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the bass speakers working on a Yoga pro 9 14IRP8 with Pop OS 22.04.

I followed [this comment](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217449#c5) :

1. Install i2c-tools :

   ```
   sudo apt install i2c-tools
   ```
2. Get the i2c-bus number on which the TIAS2781 component is connected. **I don't know how to do that**. I tried the fix with 0 and it didn't work, but it worked with 1. Use at your own risks.
3. Download [this script](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=304763) and run it as sudo :

   ```
   sudo bash ./2pa-byps.sh 1
   ```

   where you replace 1 by the bus number that works for you.

Your subwoofers should work at this point. You need to run the script after each reboot, personally I added it to my root's cron.

The only remaining problem is that the system volume doesn't control the applications volume, so I have to set each app volume from the sound settings (same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487030/system-volume-doesnt-change-app-volume)). It's annoying but it's better than having no bass.

Comment: This really worked for me, thank you... I used 0, I did not find how to get the right number yet either.

Comment: To find the bus number:
`ls -l /sys/bus/i2c/devices/`
and check which of `i2c-#` you get for TIAS2781