# MIDI keyboard along with accompaniment qsynth

Tags: sound, keyboard

I recently got the MIDI keyboard connected on my ubuntu 19.04 using qsynth referring to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147052/step-by-step-to-run-a-midi-keyboard-input-device-12-04). 
I can now hear the keys when I play. 
But, I can't still hear the auto-accompaniments (Rhythms and in-built Chords).  I use a CASIO 7300IN.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

This is **NOT** a qsynth or audio driver setting. All the channels were correctly configured. This is a configurable MIDI setting on the keyboard to allow/disallow auto-accompaniment. On my keyboard, it was disabled by default.