# How do I install a .src.tgz file?

Tags: wine

I want to install Synthesia, but the creators didn't bother with a Linux version (as usual). They said it would run under Wine 1.4, but my wine is higher than that apparently, and I don't know how to downgrade it. However, I saw that someone had made a Linux version called Linthesia [hypertext removed due to low reputation - <10 reputation = >2 links not allowed in posts] and put it up on Sourceforge in the form of a .src.tgz file. I have installed both Synthesia and Linthesia and currently am able to use neither (the audio doesn't work in Synthesia under my current version of Wine). Could someone please walk me through the steps of either installing Linthesia from the .src.tgz file or downgrading my Wine.

Thanks,
Num

Yes, there is a README in the .src.tgz file. There is also a makefile, but when I tried to make, it didn't work because the files are still in the .src.tgz and not on my computer. Here is a screenshot of the contents of the file.

Ariel, your answer worked until it came to installing the build dependencies. I installed  build-essential and it worked fine. I then tried to install the rest of the packages and got error messages, which can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uuwg.png).

Comment: Support for a third party application is going to be limited at best. Why not use a linux native solution ? What are you trying to do exactly? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/141344/how-to-play-piano-via-a-midi-keyboard and http://askubuntu.com/questions/19764/how-does-one-set-up-a-midi-keyboard/19768#19768

Comment: Also, you state you installed both apps, but it is not working. What did yod do exactly?

Comment: I downloaded the .src.tgz from SourceForge and the Synthesia.exe from the Synthesia website.

Comment: What is in the src.tgz? Is there a README? There is a .deb on the website as well, did you try that?

Comment: Which website? a .deb would make this whole process so much easier.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linthesia/files/v0.4/ , direct link http://sourceforge.net/projects/linthesia/files/v0.4/linthesia_0.4-1_i386.deb/download

Comment: I have an amd64 arch. I'd like and amd64 version of the software.

Comment: Their readme is very terse. You can try to compile it - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo . You will have to resolve dependencies yourself. I did not see any listed.

Comment: you don't really need a 64-bit version of a software, it's nice and it sounds good but you don't really need it, unless it's using loads of RAM and such.

Comment: The .deb isn't working.

Comment: I ran it and it did nothing, I updated it and ran in terminal and it gave lots of errors, if you want a screenshot of the errors I'd be glad to give one.

Comment: Just run the Windows version in WINE. The higher version will only help, most likely.

Comment: It doesn't. 1.4 and below are the only ones that work.

Comment: And I tried that already. Did you read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the .tgz in a directory of your choice. I usually pick `/tmp` for speed:

```
cd /tmp
tar -xzvf linthesia-0.4-2.src.tgz
```

Install `build-essential` and the packages specified in `linthesia/BUILD-DEPENDS`:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtkmm-2.4-dev \
libgconfmm-2.6-dev libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev libasound2-dev
```

Since there is no `configure` script, compile right away, passing `DESTDIR=your_destination_directory`:

```
make install DESTDIR=/opt/linthesia
```

Comment: See post edits above